# Cassandra Data Model for count of event properties

Tags: solr, cassandra, data-modeling, datastax-enterprise

I am trying to create a data model that allows for dynamic properties to be counted, so that I can easily look up how many times a key:value pair has occurred.

My data model for storing the raw events (not the issue):

```
CREATE TABLE events (
  id text PRIMARY KEY,
  event_type varchar,
  user_id text,
  properties map<text, text>,
  date_to_day varchar
)
```

My data model for storing the event property counts:

```
CREATE TABLE event_property_counts (
  event_type varchar,
  user_id int,
  property varchar,
  value varchar,
  date_to_day varchar,
  count counter,
  sum counter,
  PRIMARY KEY ((event_type, user_id), property, value, date_to_day)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (property DESC, value DESC, date_to_day DESC);
```

The indexing is right for my use case, but I want to be able to query something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM event_property_counts WHERE property = 'name' AND value = 'George';
```

This does work fine, but if I then want to get the count of how many times 2 different key:value pairs appeared together, I try this:

```
SELECT * FROM event_property_counts WHERE property = 'name' AND value = 'George';
SELECT * FROM event_property_counts WHERE property = 'age' AND value = '7';
```

This doesn't work though, as there may be many events that have a key:value pair of `age:7` without a `name:George` pair. This means that I'm really doing an `"OR"` query rather than what I need: an `"AND"` query.

I was then mocking up a similar data model:

```
CREATE TABLE event_property_counts_serialized (
  event_type varchar,
  user_id int,
  properties varchar,
  date_to_day varchar,
  count counter,
  sum counter,
  PRIMARY KEY ((event_type, user_id), properties, date_to_day)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (properties DESC, date_to_day DESC);
```

Which would allow me to query like (or similar to) this:

```
SELECT * FROM event_property_counts_serialized WHERE properties = 'name:George,age:7'
```

BUT, again this doesn't quite work, as if I want to specify 2 out of 3 properties that the event has, and I miss the property that happens to be serialized in between the 2 I specify, the select won't match any rows.

Then I thought - what if I simply store EVERY permutation/combination of the serialized properties, i.e:

```
1: name:George,age:7,location:Australia
2: location:Australia,age:7,name:George
3: age:7,name:George,location:Australia
```

AND

```
4: age:7
5: age:7,name:George
etc....
```

But for an event with 10 properties, this just gets ridiculous.

I have searched far and wide and can't seem to find anyone doing what I am trying to do with a data model.

***Also:*** I've been playing around with Solr with Datastax's Enterprise edition of Cassandra, and I can achieve the kind of searching power I need, but it's not as quick as simply pulling out a count from Cassandra.

**Main question:** What does it look like to create the kind of model I'm looking for?